# Multiple NSURLSession to load Json

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsurlsession

I want to load two `NSURLSession`. The problem is that in the second `NSURLSession` I need a key which is given by the first `NSURLSession`.

This is what I did but it doesn't seem working !

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) { (data, response, error) in
     do {

let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers)

// fetching items from json ...

for item in items {


 // I extract an ID from each item

 let myID = item["id"] as! String
  /* Here is the problem I want to call another NSURLSession with 
   a url that contains this myID (String) */



 let url2 = NSURL(string:"http://example.com/something?ID=\(myID)")
 NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url2!) { (data2, response2, error2) in
     do {

   //The problem is that this code is not executed in each for loop !

       } catch let jsonError2 {
            print(jsonError2)
        }  

}.resume()





  }

       } catch let jsonError {
            print(jsonError)
        }  

}.resume()
```

What should I do?

Comment: If they're calling the same web server then I'd suggest you to handle it internally on the server side - just a thought

Comment: Since the task works asynchronously just put the code of the second task into the completion block of the first.

Comment: @PinchusG. The server is not mine it's Third part API

Comment: @vadian That's what i did . No ?

Comment: are you sure items.count > 1?

Comment: My bad. Yes, indeed. The code indentation is a bit confusing. First of all you have to unwrap the optional `id` value, otherwise you get a literal unintended  *optional* in the URL

Comment: @vadian Yes It is unwrapped in my code in Xcode

Comment: can you mention the api if It is public

Comment: @hariszaman I'm getting the items from PlayList  ( YouTube api v3 ) then I load supplementary data by calling the API for each video id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, the solution was to keep this code and to add a function that sort the data in the array.